# Are there words in English which written as "ch" and pronounce as "sh"?

Tags: pronunciation, digraphs

Are there words in English which written as "**ch**" and pronounce as "**sh**"?

For now, I know that "**ch**" pronounced as K in chemistry or as "ch" in chips or chief.

Comment: I've heard ***niche*** pronounced as ***neesh***.

Comment: "Charade", "cliché", "cache", "niche" (at least in BrE), "recherché", "Boche", "cloche", "mache", "machete" (sometimes), "papier-maché", "chemise", "chandelier", "chic", "charabanc"...

Comment: *Niche*, *corniche*, *bardiche*, *fiche*, *microfiche*, *moustache*, *pastiche*, among others.  (*Niche* is often pronounced like *nitch* in US English, but not in other dialects.)

Comment: "Are there any" questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange; on the one hand it is impossible to prove a negative, and on the other, you have a list of indefinite length from which there is no one single definitive answer. The short answer, however, is that, at least, numerous modern borrowings from French have this pronunciation, e.g. *quiche*, *chic*.

Comment: "Charlatan" is a good one too.

Comment: You may add [**douche**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douche) to the list

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a few English words in which [“ch” is pronounced as “sh”](https://jakubmarian.com/english-words-in-which-ch-is-pronounced-as-sh-an-exhaustive-list/):

> machine /məˈʃiːn/ (mə-sheen) is piece of equipment with movable parts.
>
> mustache /məˈstɑːʃ/ (mə-staash) UK, /ˈmʌstæʃ/ (mʌ-stæsh) or /məˈstæʃ/ (mə-stæsh) US is a type of facial hair growing between the mouth and the nose.
>
> chef /ʃef/ (shef) is a professional senior cook.
>
> chic /ʃiːk/ (sheek) means “fashionable and elegant”.

Etc.

Source: jakubmarian.com

A bit of history:

***[ch](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ch)***:

> digraph used in Old French for the "tsh" sound. In some French dialects, including that of Paris (but not that of Picardy), Latin ca- became French "tsha." ***This was introduced to English after the Norman Conquest, in words borrowed from Old French such as chaste, charity, chief (adj.).*** Under French influence, -ch- also was inserted into Anglo-Saxon words that had the same sound (such as bleach, chest, church) which in Old English still was written with a simple -c-, and into those that had formerly been spelled with a -c- and pronounced "k" such as chin and much.
>
> ***As French evolved, the "t" sound dropped out of -ch-, so in later loan-words from French -ch- has only the sound "sh-"*** (chauffeur, machine (n.), chivalry, etc.).

Source: Etymonline

Comment: "Moustache" is the UK spelling.